# Signout using firebase in Android Studio: getProviderData() returns null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I am a new bee to android, I created a simple sign in method with Firebase where I included sign in using Email, Facebook and google.I created the bellow sign out function. But when I click the signout method, second time it does not ask for authentication for facebook and google. Can anybody help me! please don't freak out if anything is wrong, I am very new to this.

```
private void OnClickSignOut(){
    sign_out_btn =(Button)findViewById(R.id.logout_btn);
    finish();
    //startActivity(new Intent(ProfileActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
    sign_out_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();

            for (UserInfo user: FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getProviderData()) {
                if (user.getProviderId().equals("facebook.com")) {
                    System.out.println("User is signed in with Facebook");
                    LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                    startActivity(new Intent(ProfileActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
                }
                else if(user.getProviderId().equals("google.com")){
                    mGoogleSignInClient.signOut().addOnCompleteListener(ProfileActivity.this,
                            new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    startActivity(new Intent(ProfileActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
                                }
                            });
                }
                else{
                    startActivity(new Intent(ProfileActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: There is a `finish()` statement immediately before the onClick listener is being set. Is the code within the listener being executed at all?

Comment: @TheGamer007 Thanks for pointing out. I moved the finish after each startActivity command. But the getProviderData() is returning null and the app is crashing. How do I handle this?

Comment: Could you post the exact error log? `getProviderData` usually returns an empty list rather than `null` AFAIK. Maybe `getCurrentUser` is the one returning `null`?

Comment: @TheGamer007 Thanks! you suspected it correct. getCurrentUser was returning null. This is because in the first statement itself i signed-out the user and then I was checking for current user. I have another problem now, I am correctly able to check if user is logged in with facebook, but I am unable to check the same if the user is logged in with google account. Can you please help me regarding this?

Comment: The provider ID for Google is indeed "google.com" according to the docs. Please check if that block of code is being entered (by placing a breakpoint or log statement). Also check the output of `getProviderId` before the `if-else` blocks, so that we can manually verify.

Comment: @TheGamer007 I am getting a very interesting result from the logcat. The Logcat result and the updated code I am posting it on the answer below.

Comment: @TheGamer007 I am also getting an error :Error while reading domain filter from WHAPI

Answer (score 0):

While initial problem is solved by changing the position of finish statement. 
But after modifying the code I ran into other problems. The identifier returns google.com but does not enter the loop. on clicking the logout button for second time the app crashes. Below is the code and Logcat[Logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHUfQ.png)

```js
                for (UserInfo user: FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getProviderData()) {
                   Log.d("***************1.Check provider "+user.getProviderId(),"check");
                    if (user.getProviderId().equals("facebook.com")) {
                        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                        System.out.println("User is signed in with Facebook");
                        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                        startActivity(new Intent(ProfileActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
                        Log.d("Signout","Facebook Clicked");
                        finish();
                    }
                    Log.d("***************2.Check provider "+user.getProviderId(),"check");
                    if(user.getProviderId().equals("google.com")){
                        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                        mGoogleSignInClient.signOut().addOnCompleteListener(ProfileActivity.this,
                                new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                        System.out.println("User is signed in with Google");
                                        startActivity(new Intent(ProfileActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
                                        Log.d("****Signout","Google Clicked");
                                        finish();
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                    else{
                        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                        startActivity(new Intent(ProfileActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
                        System.out.println("User is signed in with email");
                        Log.d("****Signout","email signedout");
                        finish();
                    }
                }
```